# How is malware removed from binary executeables?

Tags: reverse-engineering, malware

[The malware museum](http://archive.org/details/malwaremuseum) has samples of DOS virusses, but surprisingly without the malware payload, only the visual effects such as the LSD remain.

How exactly has the malicous *code* been removed from the malware samples? *“sterilized malware”*

Answer (score 2):

The malware videos you see on the webpage is running in an emulator, the downloaded ZIP file contains the real malicious sample, do not execute them on your machine ;)

[image]